# XINU - How can I take control over an interrupt vector

Tags: c, operating-system, interrupt, xinu

Well, I've met this question a lot in OS, we've implemented this by diff. ways (Inline Assembly with setvect, getvect, etc..)

At XINU it's a little bit different and I'm trying to figure this out.

What I found so far, which may be correct but I want to confirm that.

I need to use `mapinit(vec_numner,myNewISR,minor_device_number);` function.
Where should I use it?

myNEWISR function, should I declare it it `initiali.c` and then implement that function at `initiali.c` or just use and `extern other_file_name.c` and implement that there. or it doesn't matter, both approaches are correct/wrong?

After I finish with that newISR, I need to restore the old vector interrupts with `maprestore()` - where should I call that function? as the last line of myNewISR's code? as the last line of `xmain()`?

Am I missing some step through that process?

I'll update this post if I find some more insights about this procedure so others also can learn from that.

Comment: Woah.. they still teach xinu... Not that it is a bad thing.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I know right? Such a useless course. Waste of time but in the end 40% of my exam mark.

Comment: Well.. I actually said it is *not* a bad thing :) It gives the concepts nicely.. well as far as I can remember from like 20 years ago.... Well one can argue it's better to start with real-life OS right away.

Comment: We learn both, that XINU part is in the OS II course. I guess they're not synced with the industry yet so they teach what they know. Unfortunately. @EugeneSh.